# when we declared number datatype in oracle what it will take default data type?

Tags: oracle, hive

I was declared one column in oracle datatype is number `ex:cust_acc_no  NUMBER (9)  DEFAULT (0)`,.

After creating table that column take double datatype why?

but that column is account number so when i select that particular field it shows account numbers with decimal.

Comment: An account number is not a number for doing maths, it's a string of digits. Use a character type to store it.

Comment: but its already defined in number datatype in oracle database we cant change.But while loading data into hive table that feild i.e account number shows values in decimal format so how it solve it.

Comment: How it's displayed is up to the client application. For example if you export data to Excel you can have it in any format you like. Oracle doesn’t have any type named "double" so I’m not sure what you're asking.

Comment: actually we have bank data that inforamtion stored into hive table.so table structure is already defined so we cant change .but when we write select query in hive that account number feild shows decimal format because that field declared in number datatype .so how to change inti normal

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't put any decimal numbers into it, then they aren't *decimal numbers*. If you think they are, please, post an example - copy/paste your SQL*Plus session which shows what you're saying. I suspect that it is matter of *formatting*, not data storage.

By the way, you could have used the INT datatype, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test (cust_acc_no int default 0);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 100 from dual union
  3    select 0.5 from dual union
  4    select 20.6 from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

CUST_ACC_NO
-----------
          1
         21
        100

SQL>
```

Comment: As I said: copy/paste your SQL*Plus session. I can't debug something I can't see.

Comment: field declaerd in number datatype not int in oracle

Comment: Certainly it is. As Oracle doesn't have the INT(EGER) datatype but supports that ANSI SQL datatype, once you create a column as INT, it has only the "integer" portion, without its decimal part which means that it'll store only whole numbers. Accept that fact and move on.

Comment: but its alredy defined in server we cant change it.thats the issue

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Could you, please, edit your initial message (question you posted) and copy/paste your SQL*Plus session which shows what you currently have, and then explain what you'd want to have.